# How to delete rows with no values in both columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am working with a excel spreadsheet that has two columns for numbers (eg debits in one column and credits in one column)There is other data in other columns. Eg There is Data in columns A, B, C and D and Debit in column E and Credit in column F. I want to delete all the rows if both columns E and F are zero. (zero is indicated by -). Please give me tips on how to do this in the least possible time. I tried doing an 'if' formula. But it did now work.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could add a column (such as:G) to determining whether rows need to be deleted. The formula could be `=IF($E2="-",IF($F2="-","Delete","Keep"),"Keep")`. Then you could select whole column G > click Data > Filter > select "Delete", delete the rows shown exclude headers .

Answer (score 0):

Use the Filter option.

Apply Filter on the data from column A to F. 

Use Filter on Column E and select '-'. 

Repeat same steps on Column F.

Delete the rows.